# Prove Convergence or Divergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, summation, divergent-series

I just need to prove either convergence or divergence for this. Having some serious trouble and would appreciate all help!

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{1/3}(1+n^{1/2})}$$

Comment: Just limit comparison with $n^{-1/3-1/2} = n^{-5/6}$ and use the fact that $n^{-p}$ converges iff $p>1$

Answer (score 1):

If you have meant  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{\frac13}\left(1+n^{\frac12}\right)}$$

The comparing Series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{\frac13}\left(n^{\frac12}\right)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{\left(\frac13+\frac12\right)}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{\frac56}}$$ which is  $p$ [Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series) with $p=\frac56$